# Read String as bytes (Oraclize callback)

Tags: solidity, string, bytes32

I have an Oraclize call that returns the following (a string):

"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8"

Now this is 1000 (bytes32 hex)

You can check here: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

Now the question is how do I read/convert this to 1000 in solidity?

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be what your looking for, it converts a hex string into bytes and gets the decimal value. Let me know if I understood your question wrong.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40247/33496