# Can string be changed to equivalent bytes and bytes32 in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I was wondering if it is possible to convert a string to a bytes32 or bytes in solidity like this, I want an input in string and require an equivalent bytes32 and bytes both.

> > input string = "0x8f54f1c2d0eb5771cd5bf67a6689fcd6eed9444d91a39e5ef32a9b4ae5ca14ff"
> > output bytes32 = 0x8f54f1c2d0eb5771cd5bf67a6689fcd6eed9444d91a39e5ef32a9b4ae5ca14ff

input string = "0xd724b8592f7962a584cfedcacc2e308292f19f5245be8bdecb42354277d3a8674266a8d0b0f2fcdcdc42bc295e2bf6378da440ed7bcb022a154c8a28a825ddb301"

output bytes = 0xd724b8592f7962a584cfedcacc2e308292f19f5245be8bdecb42354277d3a8674266a8d0b0f2fcdcdc42bc295e2bf6378da440ed7bcb022a154c8a28a825ddb301

I have already looked into this link: [How to convert a bytes32 to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string) but this is not working and returning different values than above.

Comment: The `bytes32` equivalence of a string would be the ASCII encoding of that string (not what you're describing in your question).

Comment: What's the use case for this? Can't you just make your function take `bytes32` in the first place? That would keep the gas usage a lot lower.

Comment: I am okay with the gas usage. I want to provide input as a JSON to a function. The Json contains two values as given below: '{"Data":"0x8f54f1c2d0eb5771cd5bf67a6689fcd6eed9444d91a39e5ef32a9b4ae5ca14ff","Signature":"0xd724b8592f7962a584cfedcacc2e308292f19f5245be8bdecb42354277d3a8674266a8d0b0f2fcdcdc42bc295e2bf6378da440ed7bcb022a154c8a28a825ddb301"}'. I get the values from JSON as string. Now I want to convert it to bytes and bytes32 to pass to another function which accepts bytes and bytes32 as an argument.

Comment: @goodvibration ..  i intend to get values as described in the question. Can you please suggest something. I have already tried available solutions but none of them are working

Comment: You can use https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39989/solidity-convert-hex-string-to-bytes to convert an hex string into a bytes array.

Comment: Thanks Ismael. I tried this solution but it is throwing errors and not working.

Comment: @PoojaMGupta I've modified the answer to compile with solc 0.5-0.7 it should work now.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael. I will verify the solution and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am getting following outputs

truffle(development)> PG.fromHex(hash1)
'0x008f54f1c2d0eb5771cd5bf67a6689fcd6eed9444d91a39e5ef32a9b4ae5ca14ff'

truffle(development)> hash1
'0x8f54f1c2d0eb5771cd5bf67a6689fcd6eed9444d91a39e5ef32a9b4ae5ca14ff'

Comment: @PoojaMGupta The code doesn't have any error checking. I left that part as exercise.