# Not sure why keccak hashing of encodePacked address and bytes not equal

Tags: solidity

```
        address addr1 = 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8;
        bytes memory addr2 = "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8";
        require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addr1)) == keccak256(addr2), 'not equal');
```

I would think that the above require statement evaluates to true, but it evaluates to false. Any reasoning as to why would be very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `abi.encodePacked(addr1)` is a 20 bytes array.

On the other hand `addr2` is a 42 bytes array.

Comment: Is there any way to make ```addr2``` 20 bytes?

Comment: @basketball9 You could use something like this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40247.