# convert a hex string to bytes32[] using web3js

Tags: web3js, javascript

I have a string thats 64 characters long and I need to convert it into a bytes32[] to be passed into a contract method call. How can I do it using web3js? I tried using hexToBytes in the utils package but that returns a

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: Does something like this work for you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39989/solidity-convert-hex-string-to-bytes/40247#40247?